# Need to start mysqld before ambari-server

Tags: centos-6

I am using Centos 6.2 to install a HDP cluster. The problem is that my ambari-server need Mysql on startup to be run before it when I use below

```
[root@master ~]# chkconfig --list ambari-server
ambari-server   0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
[root@master ~]# chkconfig --list mysqld
mysqld          0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
```

I am not sure how to make mysqld run before ambari-server on startup? any bash script or configuration? I am new to CentOs.

Answer (score 0):

```
# chkconfig --level 345 mysqld on
```

Comment: This answer needs an explanation.